# D-Bus connection error after Bluez 5.50 Gatt Server termination

Tags: linux, dbus, bluez

I am running a BlueZ Gatt server based upon BlueZ V5.50 and the example-gatt-server.py file contained in the BlueZ test directory. Many times when the server program exits/terminates the D-Bus is left in an unstable condition and I cannot successfully execute the program again without rebooting.

The error message received follows.  This error persists until the system is rebooted.

```
('adapter (val/add) = ', dbus.ObjectPath('/org/bluez/hci0/dev_62_D9_BD_2F_9D_DB/service0018/char0019/desc001b'), '/', '0x75e2a020')
('service_manager (val/loc) = ', <Interface <ProxyObject wrapping <dbus._dbus.SystemBus (system) at 0x75dbbea0> :1.7 /org/bluez/hci0/dev_62_D9_BD_2F_9D_DB/service0018/char0019/desc001b at 0x75e5bf90> implementing 'org.bluez.GattManager1' at 0x75db9f70>, '/', '0x75e168a0')
ERROR:dbus.connection:Unable to set arguments (dbus.ObjectPath('/'), {}) according to signature None: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Unable to guess signature from an empty dict
```

Resting bluetooth adapter power off/on has no effect

The error occurs asynchronous to the program so pdb has not helped

---

System information:

- GNU/Lunix 4.19.42-v7 #1219
- Bluez 5.50 with experimental flag set